# WordPress: Count all comments by user then count meta data on comments

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, meta

I have set some custom meta against certain comments for users using this function: `add_comment_meta( $wp_comment_id, 'accepted', true );`

What I want to do is show for each user on their profile /author/username is how many of these special comments they have so for example if a user made 20 comments and 5 had this meta data of accepted equalling true then the value would be 5.

How could I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is the latest version of wordpress.  You can see the database schema diagram here: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

I haven't tested this, but something LIKE this should do the trick:

```
<?php
getCommentCount('John', 'accepted', 'true');

function getCommentCount($author_name, $meta_key, $meta_value){
    if(empty($author_name)){
        return;
    }

    $author_name    = trim($author_name);
    $sql            = 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments . ' comments '
                    . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->commentmeta . ' meta ON comments.comment_ID = meta.comment_id '
                    . ' WHERE comments.comment_author = %s AND meta.meta_key = %s ANd meta.value = %s ';

    $commentCount   = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $author_name, $meta_key, $meta_value));

    return $commentCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand what do you mean by "count meta data"...
whice value in meta data.. do you mean the user's meta data or the comment.

Anyhow - in order to count comments by a specific user you can...
Put this code in your functions php

```
function countUserComments($userID) {
    $args = array(
        'user_id' => $userID
    );
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    echo count($comments);
}
```

The you can use it anywhere where you got a user id available to you like so

```
<?php echo countUserComments($user->ID); ?>
```

.

Hope this helps anyone ;)
Cheers, Sagive